# Inject content scripts from external urls in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that adds a small notification to the bottom corner of web pages. 
I have multiple ways to do this, being

1. Include a content.js in manifest and use the file
2. Inject a script file through `chrome.tabs.executeScript` api
3. Inject code through `chrome.tabs.executeScript` api

Now, I don't want the design of the notification to be hardcoded into the extension . I want to host a .html file and fetch it from the server whenever the notification is to be shown. By this way, I want to change the design of the notification frequently to boost engagement.

How do I inject a DOM element fetched from external sources into the webpages?

Answer (score 0):

The method of how you inject into the website is irrelevant.  You just need to make an ajax call to get the html.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourremotehtml.html",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        //append data wherever you want it on the page
    }
});
```

Depending on your details, you may want to change this up a bit.  For example, maybe there's a template and you want to use a templating language like underscore etc to change it dynamically, maybe you want to cache the html, etc.